# ASPx template to produce html as well as PDF in Windows Azure

Tags: windows, templates, pdf, azure

I have a project requirement to produce PDF files as well as HTML on a solution deployed on MS Windows Azure.  The PDF files are often printed and delivered to clients as part of a presentation as and also made available through a client portal.  Users of the client portal should also be able to interact with the information in a more interactive way via html.  So here’s my question, are there ASPx controls that allow the information to be rendered in html or pdf that run on an Azure server?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an HTML solution and convert each page to PDF when needed. There are several tools that can help you with this:

1. [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) (LGPL, command
   line applicacion)
2. [Amyuni WebkitPDF](http://www.amyuni.com/en/server/webkitpdf/), a HTML to PDF/XAML conversion library (free
   for commercial and non-commercial use, Windows library with C#
   bindings)